# downloading a file with window.open shows "navigating away" message after spring'19 update

Tags: lightning

Part of application, i need to download a file from AWS S3. so in the helper js, i create presigned S3 URL and call window.open(url, '_blank'). This line of window.open was working  correctly and downloading the file from AWS S3 without any alert or warning message in salesforce.

After spring'19 salesforce update over the weekend, i'm getting alert message that says "you are exiting domainname. Continue?" . 
any experiencing this issue after spring'19 update and any work-around for disabling the confirm message.